# How to create users using external API in owncloud

Tags: owncloud

My application creates owncloud users using external APIs.

I tried with get owncloud version using external API. Below is the code I used:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost/owncloud/index.php/apps/news/api/2.0/version',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (response) {
                    // handle success
                },
                error: function () {
                    // handle errors
                },
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    var username = 'admin';
                    var password = 'admin';
                    var auth = btoa(username + ':' + password);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + auth);
                }
            });
```

The above code didn't work.

How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

The code you have put is right.

You could as well test if your api is returning the data using something like postman or chrome rest client.

then(function(response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                })
                .done(function(res) {
                    swal("Deleted!", "Your ListJds has been deleted.", "success");

```
            })
            .error(function(res) {
                res;
                swal("Delete Failure!", "Please Try Again.", "error");
            });
        })
```